DriverError When Extracting Features From ESRI Map Service
I am running this code to extract the features from an ArcGIS Map Server into a geodataframe (modified from this Medium article):
import urllib.request
import json
import requests
import geopandas as gpd

# define query
SERVICE_URL = ("https://dghostingexternalmapprod.eversource.com/dghosting/rest/services/DG_Hosting_Final/DG_Hosting_EMA_Final/MapServer/0")
QUERY_URL = f"{SERVICE_URL}/query"
where = "1=1"

# Determine the total number of records for the given where clause
count_params = {
    "where": where,
    "returnCountOnly": True,
    "f": "json"
}

# determine number of records and size of each query
query_json = requests.get(QUERY_URL, params=count_params).json()
tot_records = query_json["count"]

service_json = requests.get(SERVICE_URL, params={'f': 'json'}).json()
step = service_json["maxRecordCount"]

# Fields we want in the output
fields = ('ESRI_OID','NSTAR_CIRCUITID', 'DIST_SUB_NAME')

# Define query parameters
query_params = {
    "where": where,
    "outFields": ', '.join(fields),
    "outSr": 2249,  # query from 'Spatial Reference'
    "f": "geojson",  # Format that geopandas can understand
    "orderByFields": "ESRI_OID",  # Avoid duplicates when offsetting
    "returnGeometry": True,
    "resultRecordCount": step
}

gdfs = []
for offset in range(0, tot_records, step):
    query_params['resultOffset'] = offset
    offset_query = urllib.parse.urlencode(query_params)
    offset_query_url = f"{QUERY_URL}?{offset_query}"
    offset_gdf = gpd.read_file(offset_query_url)
    gdfs.append(offset_gdf)

Which yields: DriverError: '/vsimem/6a50261673ab4872ad3fae15188a05af' not recognized as a supported file format
I think the issue is because the Map Service does not support pagination - is there a recommended workaround?
